# Build errors in Xcode

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

My app works fine in Chrome/Safari web browsers but when I try to run it from Xcode I get an error. I only started getting this error once I added the `cordova` *plugin* **Network Information** via `cordova plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information`

Also, I'm on cordova 4.3.0 and Xcode 6.3.1. Is there any way to get past this currently?

**Xcode error**

```
Ld /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.app/blankApp normal arm64
    cd "/Users/Default/Sites/MyAppƒ/blankApp/platforms/ios"
    export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=6.0
    export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS8.3.sdk -L/Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -filelist /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/blankApp.LinkFileList -dead_strip -weak_framework CoreFoundation -weak_framework UIKit -weak_framework AVFoundation -weak_framework CoreMedia -weak-lSystem -ObjC -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -miphoneos-version-min=6.0 -framework AssetsLibrary /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libCordova.a -framework CoreGraphics -framework MobileCoreServices -framework CoreMotion -framework CoreLocation -weak_framework SystemConfiguration -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/blankApp_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.app/blankApp

duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVConnection._callbackId in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-1CADCF0E5137048B.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-8352C031B56FFD70.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVConnection.connectionType in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-1CADCF0E5137048B.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-8352C031B56FFD70.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVConnection.internetReach in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-1CADCF0E5137048B.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-8352C031B56FFD70.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVConnection.type in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-1CADCF0E5137048B.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-8352C031B56FFD70.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVConnection in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-1CADCF0E5137048B.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-8352C031B56FFD70.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVConnection in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-1CADCF0E5137048B.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVConnection-8352C031B56FFD70.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVReachability.reachabilityRef in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVReachability-20459C55ECAAB2A7.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVReachability-A1ACF8C458D4507A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_IVAR_$_CDVReachability.localWiFiRef in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVReachability-20459C55ECAAB2A7.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVReachability-A1ACF8C458D4507A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_CDVReachability in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVReachability-20459C55ECAAB2A7.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVReachability-A1ACF8C458D4507A.o
duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_CDVReachability in:
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVReachability-20459C55ECAAB2A7.o
    /Users/Default/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/blankApp-hkvrfpembsxtsxdafnzhlomraujc/Build/Intermediates/blankApp.build/Debug-iphoneos/blankApp.build/Objects-normal/arm64/CDVReachability-A1ACF8C458D4507A.o
ld: 10 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

## Solution

Here's what worked for me:

1. `$ ./platforms/ios/cordova/clean`
2. `$ sudo ionic plug remove cordova-plugin-network-information`
3. `$ sudo ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information`
4. `$ sudo ionic build ios`

Comment: Have you tried running a clean in xcode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you add some plugins , ios build start failing for no apparent reason. Most of the time this is nothing to do with the plugin.

Removing the platform and adding it back again worked for me all the time.

try removing and adding the platform(s) again

`ionic platform remove ios`

`ionic platform add ios`

read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27087018/ionic-cordova-ios-build-fails-after-adding-media-plugin) about the same king of an issue and the solutions

HTH

Comment: I removed, added, cleaned, and built. I'm getting the same error but oddly enough now it's complaining about duplicate symbols for `x86_64` instead of `arm64`.

Comment: Worked after: 1) `$ ./platforms/ios/cordova/clean` 2) `$ sudo ionic plug remove cordova-plugin-network-information` 3) `$ sudo ionic plugin add https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information` 4) `$ sudo ionic build ios`