# Error on ionic build command

Tags: ionic-framework

i am facing this error when i want to run `ionic build android` command.
i tried everything and obviously i have no idea what to do here .

i have SDK and JDK , Gradle and other things .
if i run the ionic serve command it works with no problem and the app shown in the browser but i can't build the app with build command .

i installed the cordova and ionic using this tutorial http://learn.ionicframework.com/videos/windows-android/ and i think i dont miss anything around here .

when i run `android` command , it shown up the android sdk manager with the API installed , when i run `gradle` it works . but this one does not work

here is the picture of the error :

[image: ionic error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to me with `ios` builds and re-installing the platform will always worked for me. try that

```
ionic platform remove android

ionic platform add android
```

[read here on almost the same thing (but with ios)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30468633/build-errors-in-xcode/30470156#30470156)

HTH

Comment: Hello , thank you for your comment . i tried it and now i got different error . check it out http://i59.tinypic.com/zna32g.jpg

Comment: have a look at this question on the same error code (error code 8) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23513768/command-line-failed-with-exit-code-8-in-phonegap-cordova